# What is the best way to create deployable package with database creation for Windows Azure?

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, cloud, webdeploy

I am working on an ASP.NET web application. The idea is that it will be sold as a "package" for simple deployment. I've made webdeploy based ZIP package for deploying directly from IIS (Import Application feature). It allows user to specify all settings (names, users, passwords) in a text fields. Then everything (even database) is deployed, configured and ready to use without any deep knowledge or manual configuration.

I would like to have the same experience when someone would like to deploy my application to Azure. I mean everything should be in one package and person responsible for deployment should only fill in few text boxes to configure and deploy whole application (with database its structure and initial data)

The question is: Is it possible? If yes where can I find any information?

Thanks,
Marcin

Comment: There are so many variables at hand it's hard to even begin to answer you question. So let me go the other way around: why don't you try? Opening an account in Azure takes about 30 seconds. OK... perhaps 40 seconds... :)  So many things can go wrong, like expecting to have the right security credentials, creating a SQL Azure database (what kind of database do you need? MySQL? On which machine?), if you need access to the registry, if your code expects a C drive... and so forth.

Comment: Herve, Marcin is using WebDeployment package. I don't think you can deploy any other DB, but SQL Server via WebDeploy package. As for DB, you just supply connection string, or a Server/user/pass/db to the WebDeployment process, so it doesn't really matter the "machine"

Answer (score 0):

Well,

For possible - it is possible. But is there out-of-the-box a tool that could provide what you are looking for? I don't think, but frankly I haven't searched for such.

The possible thing - you have to provide an "application installer" yourself (like Umbraco installer, WordPress Installer, etc.), and do it thinking "cloud-wise". So that you provide the package, your customer uploads it to their cloud service, and then a UI asking the questions for user/password runs.

Your other option for Azure would be going multi-tenant way with [Azure App MarketPlace](https://datamarket.azure.com/browse/Applications) ([intro lab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_introtowazmarketplace.aspx)), where you will have a full SaaS provided to your customers.

I am thinking about your last chance - using the Windows Azure WebSites as target platform for your app. But, frankly I am not sure whether you can supply a web-deploy package directly. There is web-deploy agent, and you can web-deploy from Visual Studio directly to WAWS (Windows Azure Web Sites), but I don't think it will work for the SQL server database generation etc.